# Lotus/ibm/HCL Notes - JVM: Java Virtual Machine failed to Start

Tags: lotus-domino, lotus, hcl-notes

When trying to run any Java related code in my Notes Client I get the above error. I also get it in the designer client when creating or accessing any Java Web Services.

This is from my log

[1460:0002-2960] 06/08/2021 11:32:22   Agent  error: Exception in thread "(unnamed thread)"

[1460:0002-2960] 06/08/2021 11:32:22   Agent  error: java/lang/ExceptionInInitializerError

[1460:0002-2960] 06/08/2021 11:32:22   Agent  error: java/lang/NullPointerException

[1460:0002-2960] 06/08/2021 11:32:22   Agent  error: JVMJ9VM015W Initialization error for library jclse7b_28(14): JVMJ9VM009E J9VMDllMain failed

[1460:0002-2960] 06/08/2021 11:32:22   JVM: The Java Virtual Machine creation returned an invalid JVM machine pointer.

[1460:0002-2960] 06/08/2021 11:32:22   JVM: Java Virtual Machine failed to start

Looking around the internet this looks like "jclse7b_28(14)" might be a misleading error and the cause is actually "java.security.AccessControlException"

My client is 9.0.1
Revision 20131022.1138 (Release 9.0.1)

We have tried reinstalling the Notes, Designer and Admin Clients

Any ideas would be appreciated

Thanks,

Nigel

Comment: What has changed since it last worked on your computer?

Comment: Thanks Karl. I only got this laptop in January when I started at the company. This is the first time I have needed to run any Java so it is possible it has never worked. I cannot open the Java Debug Console, run a java agent and when I access a Java web service the client crashes, all with the same error logged

Comment: https://ds_infolib.hcltechsw.com/ldd/ndseforum.nsf/xpTopicThread.xsp?documentId=4FF165E8E82D545A85257DBD007138A3  suggests that it may be an issue with FP2.

Comment: Thanks, I don't think it is the FP2 problem, others with the same version as me are fine. I am going to try uninstalling again, deleting all Notes related files and reinstall

Answer (score 1):

We got it working by uninstalling the Notes, Designer and Admin Clients and all files relating to lotus Notes (keeping copies of the id, names.nsf etc). We also uninstalled Java (not really sure that was required).

When we reinstalled everything the JVM worked.

Thanks to Karl and Duston for their responses